# Discord.py add reaction to a users message

Tags: python, discord

```
#reaction ✅
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!on'):
        await message.add_reaction('✅')
    if message.content.startswith('!off'):
        await message.add_reaction('✅')
```

> **I have a problem with discord.py adding a reaction to a message. I have done it so it car
> react to the message but I cant excecute any other command**